# Managing typical excel formula errors in vba functions

Tags: vba, excel, error-handling

I'm writing some vba functions. 
In particular, i'm rewriting the VLOOKUP...
In this MY_VLOOKUP, I have two boolean variable :
1. error_range, it's true if the range passed in the formula arguments is invalid
2. not_ava, it's true  if there is no result (the VLOOKUP result would be #N/A)

In the error handler section i wrote

```
Errorhandler:
If error_range Then error_cat = xlErrRef
If not_ava Then error_cat = xlErrNA
Err.Raise error_cat
```

but I get a "#VALUE" error in the cell. 
When debugging, i realised that err.raise doesn't work and generates this "#VALUE" error
How can i get a "#N/D" o "#REF" error in the cell?

Answer (score 0):

You can get many errors when using Excel Formulas. They can be like `#Ref`, `#Value`,`#N/A`, `#Name` etc.

I usually use `CVERR()` to trap these kind of errors. Here is an example.

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim Ret As Variant
    Dim error_cat As Long

    On Error GoTo Whoa

    Ret = Application.Evaluate("=VLOOKUP(12,SiddharthRout,1,0)") '<~~ Invalid Range
    'Ret = Application.Evaluate("=VLOOKUP(12,D3:G7,1,0)")   '<~~ No Value found

    Select Case CVErr(Ret)
        Case CVErr(xlErrName): error_cat = xlErrName
        Case CVErr(xlErrNA): error_cat = xlErrNA
        Case CVErr(xlErrRef): error_cat = xlErrRef
        Case CVErr(xlErrValue): error_cat = xlErrValue
    End Select

    If error_cat <> 0 Then Err.Raise error_cat

LetsContinue:
    MsgBox "Phew!"
    Exit Sub
Whoa:
    MsgBox "Error Error Damn Error"
    Resume LetsContinue
End Sub
```

Comment: thank you! your solutions gave me the right way. i didn't know the use of CVErr I solved my problem with this code in the error handling section: If error_range Then error_cat = xlErrRef End If If not_ava Then error_cat = xlErrNA else error_cat = xlErrValue End If my_vlookup = CVErr(error_cat )

Comment: Glad to be of help :)

Answer (score 0):

I paste the code , maybe it will bu useful for someone

(thanks to Siddharth Rout for the help)

```
If error_range Then 
error_cat = xlErrRef 
Else
If not_ava Then 
error_cat = xlErrNA 
else 
error_cat = xlErrValue 
End If 
end if
my_vlookup = CVErr(error_cat )
```