# How can I input same value in place of Vlookup `#N/A`

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

I want to update Port codes from its short form. Suppose I have port code `DMM`. I `VLOOKUP` this  cell against `SADMM`. It means if I type `DMM`, I will get `SADMM`. But if I dont have `DMM`, it will show `#N/A`. Instead of this I want `DMM`; the original value if `VLOOKUP` cant find the Value.

**Code**

```
Sub Vlookup_POD()
    On Error Resume Next
    
    Dim rng As Range, FinalResult As Variant, Table_Range As Range, LookupValue As Range

    Set rng = Sheets("Sheet3").Range(Range("I14"), Range("I14").End(xlDown))

    Set Table_Range = Sheets("Pod").Range("A1:B25")

    Set LookupValue = Sheets("Sheet3").Range(Range("I14"), Range("I14").End(xlDown))
    'Range ("I14:I500")

    FinalResult = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(LookupValue, Table_Range, 2, False)
    rng = FinalResult
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually use `IsError()` to trap these kind of errors. Here is an example.

```
FinalResult = Application.VLookup(LookupValue, Table_Range, 2, False)

If IsError(FinalResult) Then FinalResult = LookupValue

rng.Value = FinalResult
```

**Note**: If I want to trap a specific error then I use [CVERR()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30436187/managing-typical-excel-formula-errors-in-vba-functions)

One more tip. Avoid the use of `On Error Resume Next` unnecessarily. Use it only when required. Or better still, do correct error handling.

Comment: You would also exponentially improve the performance of your code by using a "vba dictionary" to perform your lookups. Although sometimes useful, in most usecases it's better to not use worksheet functions in vba.

Comment: My post only deals with the current problem that OP has. Feel free to post an answer to suggest alternative code to improve performance of the original code :)

Answer (score 0):

@Siddharth Rout, was not a criticism :(

Alternative approach using a dictionary:

```
    Sub DictMatch()
        'set vars
        Dim arr, arr2, j As Long, dict As Object
        Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary") 'create dictionary lateB
        
        'source = lookupVars
        arr = Sheet1.Range("A1:A" & Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row).Value2 'load source
        For j = 1 To UBound(arr) 'traverse source
            dict(arr(j, 1)) = Empty
        Next j
        
        'compare
        arr2 = Sheet2.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Value2 'load source
        For j = 1 To UBound(arr2)
            If dict.Exists(arr2(j, 1)) Then 'matching happens here, compare data from target with dictionary
                arr(j, 1) = arr2(j, 2) 'write to target array if match
            End If
        Next j
        
        'dumb to sheet
        With Sheet1
            .Range(.Cells(1, 2), .Cells(UBound(arr), 2)) = arr 'dumping in col 2 but if you want to replace just change col nr
        End With
    End Sub
```

Comment: Oh I did not feel bad. I was simply encouraging you to post an answer ;)

Comment: How do Sheet1 and Sheet2 relate to Sheets("Sheet3") and Sheets("Pod") in the question ?

Comment: well it wouldn't be fun if it's just copy paste wouldn't it.

Comment: if `arr2 = Sheets("Pod").Range("A1:B25")` how does `For j = 1 To UBound(arr2)` update all the elements in arr if say `UBound(arr)` is 100 ?

Comment: It doesn't. Only col 1 an 2 are used. Col 1 for the lookup, col2 for the value that replaces the org value in arr. only when their is a match ( I add the match in col 2 of the sheet  for testing but in the final version it should replace the value of col1).