# I have this Run-time error '1004': Unable to get the VlookUp property of the worksheet function class?

Tags: excel, vba

```
Private Sub cmb_Product_Change()

Dim sh As Worksheet
Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Product_Master")


If Me.cmb_Product.Value = "" Or Me.cmb_Type.Value = "" Then
    Me.txt_Rate.Value = ""
End If

If Me.cmb_Type.Value = "Sale" Then
    Me.txt_Rate.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Me.cmb_Product, sh.Range("B:D"), 2, 0)
    
ElseIf Me.cmb_Type.Value = "Purchase" Then
    Me.txt_Rate.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Me.cmb_Product, sh.Range("B:D"), 3, 0)
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: That means the Vlookup didn't find a match in column B.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67646591/how-can-i-input-same-value-in-place-of-vlookup-n-a